# Inserting rows for grandparents and great grandparents

Tags: php, mysql

I'v created a query to display a table that lists all the state birds, where GS.Symbol = a bird's common name (e.g. robin) and GS.Latin = its scientific name. GG.Name = the name of a state (e.g. Alaska), and GG.IDParent = 'usa'. The display looks like this:

```
<tr><td>brown thrasher</td><td>Georgia</td></tr>

<tr><td>robin</td><td>Michigan, Wisconsin</td></tr>
```

And here's the query:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GROUP_CONCAT(GG.Name) as Names, GG.IDParent
FROM gw_geog GG
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.IDArea = GG.IDArea
WHERE GG.IDParent = 'usa' AND GS.DesigGen = :RefCat
GROUP BY GS.Symbol
ORDER BY GS.Symbol, GG.Name");
$stm->execute(array(
'RefCat'=>$RefCat,
));
```

I would now like to modify my table so that the rows are ordered taxonomically, and rows featuring the names of families (grandparents) and orders (great grandparents) are inserted, like this:

```
<tr><td><b>Passeriformes</b> (order)</td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Turdidae</b> (family)</td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td>brown thrasher</td><td>Georgia</td></tr>

<tr><td>robin | Michigan</td><td>Wisconsin</td></tr>
```

The table I need to join is gz_life, and the key columns are Taxon and Parent.

Let's use the mourning dove as an example. gs.Latin = 'Zenaida-macroura', which matches a value in gz_life.Taxon. In that same row, gz_life.Parent = 'Zenaida' (a genus name). Zenaida's parent is 'Columbidae' (a family name). Columbidae's parent is 'Columbiformes' (an order name).

Those are the two values I want to retrieve - family (Columbidae) and order (Columbiformes).

```
<tr><td><b>Columbiformes</b> (order)</td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Columbidae</b> (family)</td><td>

<tr><td>mourning dove</td><td>Wisconsin</td></tr>
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: BTW, that's an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Great - I added this line to my query: INNER JOIN gz_life GZ ON GZ.Taxon = GS.Latin  But how can I extract the values for Parent, Grandparent and Great-Grandparent for each species?